# Vários replaces simultâneos com javascript

Tags: javascript

Como eu consigo fazer vários replaces simultâneos, sem ter que fazer um por um?

Exemplo: tenho uma formula, em um formato de string, cujo a imagem segue logo a baixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu já calculei todos esses valores e tenho que substituir esses valores calculados no USERS.

Tem como ao invés de fazer `formula = formula.replace(totalUsers,"USERS");` 
um por um, fazer todos esses valores simultâneos?

Comment: Coloque o texto, n]ao imagem. E explique melhor o que deseja. Está muito genérico. Substiruir o que pelo que? Coloque como se você fosse fazer um por um.

Comment: A ideia é ser generico mesmo

Comment: Gabriel ainda assim concordo com o @bigown que podes dar um exemplo mais claro e com código em texto.

Comment: Tentando ajudar: É algo assim que você precisa na sua regex?  `USERS|OPTIONS|MFPCONNECTOR|GATEWAY|HARDWARESOFTWARE|HARDWAREGATEWAY`... Veja aqui: http://regexr.com/3gps4

Answer (score 2):

O replace só substitui a primeira ocurrência se receber uma *String* como primeiro argumento. Se usares uma regex com a falg `g` substitui todos os que encontrar. Acho que é isso que procuras:

```
const regex = new RegExp(totalUsers, 'g'); // g é para multiplas ocurrências
formula = formula.replace(regex, "USERS");
```